# delphi fmx android label align to top

Tags: delphi, controls, alignment, delphi-10.3-rio

I've got 5 labels and at design time I placed 1 to the top, followed by 2 aligned to the top, followed by 3, 4 and 5 aligned to the top. If I compile and run my app on android the labels are in the order 1 5 4 3 2 and I have no clue why this is the case. I can fix it using a few rectangles or panels to put my labels onto, but I want to make use of the autosize feature of the labels and it would be awesome if I could fix the order issue of Delphi 10.3.3 Community Edition as I guess this is Delphis fault, because I just did place them onto a form and they're misbehaving with the order of my top alignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround.. The Alignment is not correct by default, so instead of

```pascal
  Label2.Visible := true;
  Label3.Visible := true;
  Label4.Visible := true;
  Label5.Visible := true;
  Label6.Visible := true;
```

I have to use

```pascal
  Label2.Visible := true;
  Label6.Visible := true;
  Label5.Visible := true;
  Label4.Visible := true;
  Label3.Visible := true;
```

then it works. I still don't know how or why this is, but if I rearrange the order of adding the Labels onto the form the "correct" (intended) order of the labels is shown. So the first item works normal and then you have to enter the other ones in the opposite order as usual, then the alignment works as intended